# How do I remove this node when a boolean is true?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I created a function that continuously spawns coins forever. 
However, I'm having trouble removing the coin that is touched by the ball that hits them. By the way, I have a variable called coinBoolean set to false in the class. Here is my code:

```
  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == groundGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ballGroup) ||
        (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == groundGroup)) { 
    }
    if ((contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == ballGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == coinGroup) ||
        (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == coinGroup && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == ballGroup)) {
        print("TRUE")
        coinBoolean = true
    }
    else {
        print("false")
        coinBoolean = false
    }
}

func addAndMoveCoins() {
    let coin = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Coin")

    coin.zPosition = 55
    coin.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width*0.9, y: randomY())
    coin.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: coin.size)
    coin.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coinGroup
    coin.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ballGroup
    coin.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    coin.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    let moveCoinLeft = SKAction.moveByX(-self.size.height, y: 0, duration: 5)
    let repeatAction1 = SKAction.repeatActionForever(moveCoinLeft)
    let removeObstacle1 = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let moveAndRemove1 = SKAction.sequence([repeatAction1, removeObstacle1])
    coin.runAction(moveAndRemove1)
    self.addChild(coin)
    if coinBoolean == true {
        coin.removeFromParent()
    }
    else if coinBoolean == false {   
    }
}

func repeatCoins() {
    let generateCoins = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(self.addAndMoveCoins), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.3)])
    let endlessAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(generateCoins)
    runAction(endlessAction)
}
```

Comment: Also I ran the function repeatCoins() in didMovetoView and didnt run the addAndMoveCoins()

Answer (score 0):

Your `coinBoolean` variable is probably changing too fast. I suggest getting the node you want to remove from the collision (bodyA or bodyB) and removing it from its parent

Answer (score 0):

Just set an action on the coin object during the contact phase instead of doing booleans.

`contact.bodyA.node.runAction(SKAction.removeFromParent())`

You would need to check if bodyA is the coin object of course